# failed to share my photo to WECHAT

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to share a photo from the Internet to WECHAT, but after I press the share button , nothing happens , I am new to Objective-C and I am unable to figure out the problem myself.Hearing that there are a lot of experts here,so is there some guy can help me solve this one? thanks in advance. here are the codes:

```
UIImage * image = [[[imageTitleArray objectAtIndex:initIndex] albumImageView] image];
       WXMediaMessage *message = [WXMediaMessage message];
       [message setThumbImage: image];
       WXImageObject *ext = [WXImageObject object];
       ext.imageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);
       message.mediaObject = ext;
       SendMessageToWXReq* req = [[[SendMessageToWXReq alloc] init]autorelease];
       req.bText = NO;
       req.message = message;
       [WXApi sendReq:req];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following method

```
- (void) sendImageContentToWeixin:(UIImage *)image {
//if the Weixin app is not installed, show an error
if (![WXApi isWXAppInstalled]) {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"The Weixin app is not installed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
return;
}
//create a message object
WXMediaMessage *message = [WXMediaMessage message];
//set the thumbnail image. This MUST be less than 32kb, or sendReq may return NO.
//we'll just use the full image resized to 100x100 pixels for now
[message setThumbImage:[image resizedImage:CGSizeMake(100,100) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault]];
//create an image object and set the image data as a JPG representation of our UIImage
WXImageObject *ext = [WXImageObject object];
ext.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
message.mediaObject = ext;
//create a request
SendMessageToWXReq* req = [[SendMessageToWXReq alloc] init];
//this is a multimedia message, not a text message
req.bText = NO;
//set the message
req.message = message;
//set the "scene", WXSceneTimeline is for "moments". WXSceneSession allows the user to send a message to friends
req.scene = WXSceneTimeline;
//try to send the request
if (![WXApi sendReq:req]) {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
}
}
```

Comment: Oddly, the Wechat API installation guide does not mention it but you also need to call `[WXApi registerApp:@"myAppId"]` on app lauching.